# Nginx Set server IP for a specific Cookie

Tags: nginx, server

What i am asking for here is:
I have 2 servers, each has an IP.
`Server 1: 10.0.0.1
Server 2: 10.0.0.2`

I want to access the First server from domain.
But for a specific cookie (if exists), i want to serve content from the second server.
How to do that?

Config for Server 1

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  Server1;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    root /var/www/server1/public;
    index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What directives do you use to serve the content from `Server 1` and/or `Server 2`? Actually a fragment of Nginx configuration would be perfect.

Comment: I use php-fpm.. I didn't do any configurations, while these are new servers. I will show the config once i can edit this question.

Comment: Okay. So you have some domain name, right? What IPs this domain name is pointing to?